# RavenDB Index: Instance field 'flags' is not defined for type 'System.Decimal'

Tags: c#, indexing, lucene, ravendb

RavenDB Index fails when I use decimal properties and I can't figure out why.

My Index:

```
public class MyIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<MyDocument>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Id { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public decimal? PreviousPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal? CurrentPrice { get; set; }
    }

    public NavEntriesIndex()
    {
        Map = entries =>
            from entry in entries
            select new Result
            {
                Id = entry.Id,
                PreviousPrice = entry.PreviousPriceMovement.Price,
                CurrentPrice = entry.PriceMovement.Price,
            };

        StoreAllFields(FieldStorage.Yes);
    }
}
```

The error:

> Failed to execute mapping function on
> 7cb4e8c7-2807-4dd2-9b42-98938acfa11f. Exception:
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'Sparrow.Utils.DecimalHelper' threw an exception.
>
> ---> System.ArgumentException: Instance field 'flags' is not defined
> for type 'System.Decimal'
>
> at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Field(Expression expression,
> String fieldName)
>
> at Sparrow.Utils.DecimalHelper.CreateIsDoubleMethod() in
> C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42046\src\Sparrow\Utils\DecimalHelper.cs:line
> 25
>
> at Sparrow.Utils.DecimalHelper..ctor() in
> C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42046\src\Sparrow\Utils\DecimalHelper.cs:line
> 18
>
> at Sparrow.Utils.DecimalHelper..cctor() in
> C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42046\src\Sparrow\Utils\DecimalHelper.cs:line
> 12
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at Raven.Server.Json.BlittableNumber.Parse(Object value, Double&
> doubleResult, Int64& longResult) in
> C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42046\src\Raven.Server\Json\BlittableNumber.cs:line
> 55
>
> at Raven.Server.Documents.Indexes.Persistence.Lucene.Documents.LuceneDocumentConverterBase.GetOrCreateNumericField(IndexField
> field, Object value, Store storage, TermVector termVector)+MoveNext()
> in
> C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42046\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Indexes\Persistence\Lucene\Documents\LuceneDocumentConverterBase.cs:line
> 595
>
> at Raven.Server.Documents.Indexes.Persistence.Lucene.Documents.LuceneDocumentConverterBase.GetRegularFields[T](T
> instance, IndexField field, Object value, JsonOperationContext
> indexContext, Boolean& shouldSkip, Boolean nestedArray) in
> C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42046\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Indexes\Persistence\Lucene\Documents\LuceneDocumentConverterBase.cs:line
> 408
>
> at Raven.Server.Documents.Indexes.Persistence.Lucene.Documents.AnonymousLuceneDocumentConverter.GetFields[T](T
> instance, LazyStringValue key, Object document, JsonOperationContext
> indexContext, IWriteOperationBuffer writeBuffer) in
> C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42046\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Indexes\Persistence\Lucene\Documents\AnonymousLuceneDocumentConverter.cs:line
> 57
>
> at Raven.Server.Documents.Indexes.Persistence.Lucene.Documents.LuceneDocumentConverterBase.SetDocument(LazyStringValue
> key, Object document, JsonOperationContext indexContext,
> IWriteOperationBuffer writeBuffer, Boolean& shouldSkip) in
> C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42046\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Indexes\Persistence\Lucene\Documents\LuceneDocumentConverterBase.cs:line
> 105
>
> at Raven.Server.Documents.Indexes.Persistence.Lucene.IndexWriteOperation.IndexDocument(LazyStringValue
> key, Object document, IndexingStatsScope stats, JsonOperationContext
> indexContext) in
> C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42046\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Indexes\Persistence\Lucene\IndexWriteOperation.cs:line
> 127
>
> at
> Raven.Server.Documents.Indexes.MapIndexBase`2.HandleMap(LazyStringValue
> lowerId, LazyStringValue id, IEnumerable mapResults,
> IndexWriteOperation writer, TransactionOperationContext indexContext,
> IndexingStatsScope stats) in
> C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42046\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Indexes\MapIndexBase.cs:line 68
>
> at
> Raven.Server.Documents.Indexes.Workers.MapDocuments.Execute(DocumentsOperationContext
> databaseContext, TransactionOperationContext indexContext, Lazy`1
> writeOperation, IndexingStatsScope stats, CancellationToken token) in
> C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42046\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Indexes\Workers\MapDocuments.cs:line 107

Any Idea?

Comment: How is the entry class in the entries collection structured?